# Split int into chunks with a max value

Tags: c#, .net, math

I've been trying to do the following, I have a max value and a int, I want to split that int like this:

```
Max = 10
Int = 45
Result = [10, 10, 10, 10, 5]
```

I already search a lot and I didn't find nothing like the thing I want to do, and my head hurts for thinking and trying to do it.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: so you want to split the int into equal chunks of a given size (=10)?

Comment: What behavior do you expect with negatives? With zeroes? Take a look at Math.DivRem as a starting point ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.divrem ).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to repeat the max the number of times it divides into your value.  Then if it does not divide evenly add the remainder.

```
int value = 45;
int max = 10;

var results = Enumerable.Repeat(max, value/max).ToList();
if(value % max != 0)
    results.Add(value % max);

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", results));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think LINQ is the nicest way to do this, but you could also have a straightforward loop approach that finds how many times the size fits into your max value, then add these numbers to a `List<int>`, and add the leftover(if any) to the list at the end.

```
var size = 10;
var max = 45;

// Find how many times the size fits and leftover
var goesInto = max / size;
var leftover = max % size;

var result = new List<int>();

// Add the sizes that fit in first
for (var i = 0; i < goesInto; i++)
{
    result.Add(size);
}

// Add leftover size at the end. 
if (leftover > 0)
{
    result.Add(leftover);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks a lot like Pseudo code. We however will write C# code, as that was the langauge tag.

```
//Need a list, or have to calculate the expected lenght. List is easier.
List<int> ResultList = new List<int>();

//Make a copy to work with
int temp = value;

//Now let us math down towards 0
while(temp>0){
  //All those multiples of Max are added first
  if(temp >= Max){
    ResultList.Add(Max);
    temp -= Max;
  }
  //We are down to the rest, here
  else{
    //If the rest is not 0, you can add it too
    if(temp > 0){
      ResultList.Add(temp);
      temp = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `=>` isn't going to work in an `if` statement like that.  `>=` is the greater than or equal to operator.

Comment: @juharr I fixed that, and another thing in the rest part.

Answer (score 0):

Here how you do in plain code without LINQ, List, etc. This will also take care of negatives

```cs
int val = -45; // negative
int max = 10;
int count = Math.Abs(val / max);
int rem = Math.Abs(val % max);
var output = new int[count + (rem == 0 ? 0 : 1)];
for(int i = 0; i < output.Length ; i++)
{
    if (i == output.Length - 1)
        output[i] = rem;
    else
        output[i] = max;
    Console.WriteLine(output[i]);
}
return output;
```

> 10
>   10
>   10
>   10
>   5

Comment: Your code to get `count` can just be `Math.Abs(val/max)` since they are `int` the result will be a whole number so there is no point in using `Floor`

Comment: @juharr Good catch